# Вывести файл в браузер на загрузку

Tags: php, codigniter

```
$htmlData = $this->load->view('account/messages/export_tpl', $data, true);

$htmlData - содержит сгенерированный `html`,теперь надо это вывести в браузер на загрузку,подскажите какие заголовки надо отправлять.
```

UPDATE: Спасибо вопрос решился встроенной в Codigniter библиотекой

```
$this->load->helper('download');
force_download('messages.html', $htmlData);
```